# Print $.post response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I have a simple web page with some option tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>Seleziona l'ente</label>
<select name="data" id="data">
    <option value="PRO - 011142764">COMUNE DI AGLIE'</option>
    <option value="PRO - 011120674">COMUNE DI AGRATE CONTURBIA</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
</form>

<script>
$('#data').change(function() {
    $.post("richiesta.php", { value: this.value });
    $('#textfield').val(this.value);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's `richiesta.php` (called from the `$.post` function):

```
<?php

function soldipubblici() {
    list($comparto, $ente) = explode("-", $_POST['value'], 2);

    $curl_parameters = array(
        'codicecomparto'    =>  trim($comparto),
        'codiceente'        =>  trim($ente),
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://soldipubblici.gov.it/it/ricerca");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query( $curl_parameters ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
    ));

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}

echo soldipubblici();

?>
```

Everything works fine. In Firebug I can see the request made from richiesta.php using the data gathered from POST is returned correctly.

[image]

I just can't find out how to print the response I see in Firebug on screen (or in the input tag)..
I tried something like:

```
$('#data').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'richiesta.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {value: this.value},
    }).done(function ( data ) {
      $('#textfield').val(data);
    });
});
```

The request still works but in `#textfield` I get `[object Object]`, not the JSON.

Comment: after `curl_close($ch);` add `return $output;`

Comment: you didn't enable `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, so by default `$output` will contain only the status code of the exec() call, NOT the contents of the url you're fetching. and since your function doesn't actually `return` anything, there's nothing to `echo` out at the point you call the function in the first place.

Comment: Plus, since you're doing a JSON request, `data` is going to be a javascript OBJECT. You'd have to encode it into a string somehow for it to be visible in your document. dumping an object into a display context liek you are will just give you `[object Object]`, not the contents of the object. if you `console.log(data)`, you'd see the contents.

Comment: Nope. I'm echoing the function. It works. The problem is not with the function, the curl function is correctly executed (I can see the resulting json in firebug).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have specified that the returned data is json (using `dataType: 'json'`), jQuery has already parsed it so it is not a string anymore, it is an object.

If you want to see it as a json string in your `#textfield`, you would have to convert it to a string again:

```
$('#textfield').val(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **JSON.stringify**.[For More Details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
$('#data').change(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'richiesta.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {value: this.value},
}).done(function ( data ) {
  var simpleData = JSON.stringify(data);
  $('#textfield').val(simpleData );
});
```

});